# HTTPDataSource error codes

Tags: android

I'm curious about debugging some of the error codes I get from the MediaPlayer... specifically the "AwesomePlayer" and "StagefrightPlayer" sub-modules



I found this "Android Open Source Project" on the internet that seems to expose some of the code driving these modules, or perhaps it is emulator-code in much the same way the public WINE source codes expose the emulators "interpretation" of the real code



https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/f6156a77044113680d038934b06bde333a1e69ea/entry/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/HTTPDataSource.cpp



but regardless of whether it is emulation or true original source, I'm interested in getting numerical translations for the following:
UNKNOWN_ERROR
ERROR_IO
ERROR_ALREADY_CONNECTED
ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED
ERROR_UNSUPPORTED


and I'm also interested in getting human-readable translations of the following numericals:
-1002
-1007


mainly I've studied the HTTPDataSource::connect and HTTPDataSource::connectWithRedirectsAndRange functions



I've browsed around some of those codeAurora pages looking at various .h files that seemed related to HTTP and MediaPlayer but couldn't find numerical translations for those error codes... I also tried using the codeAurora Search bar at the top to find them, but didn't have any luck with that either.



I'm beginning to think I need to learn how GIT works and download the whole source tree to my hard drive and then search for those #defines and the negative numbers using an advanced text editor or the VC2010 IDE



but before I do that I thought I'd post here and see if anybody has any insight, tips, or maybe even knows those codes?

Comment: ok nevermind seems I found the answer by checking these two pages:

http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h;h=6df4d86b3811352dd447cb457de24a4083a5e9d8;hb=HEAD

http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=include/utils/Errors.h;h=81f818b75d222b0c099efb062f5bd39530642211;hb=HEAD
 it looks as if:
-1002 = ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST
-1007 = ERROR_MALFORMED

Comment: and well I don't need numericals of those others so much now... reason I asked for those others was to see if any of them matched up with -1002 or -1007

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error codes here:

https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/af8ce7dda6594bb7bff9ada69051c7a9365c3b50/entry/frameworks/base/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h